# show files from folder help for asp.net

Tags: asp.net, file-io

I have a script that shows some files from a folder.

code behind

```
Sub fileinfo()
    Dim objDI As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("upload/files/"))
    Dim allFile As New ArrayList()
    allFile.AddRange(objDI.GetFiles("*.png"))
    allFile.AddRange(objDI.GetFiles("*.jpg"))
    allFile.AddRange(objDI.GetFiles("*.bmp"))
    allFile.AddRange(objDI.GetFiles("*.gif"))
    allFile.AddRange(objDI.GetFiles("*.pdf"))
    allFile.AddRange(objDI.GetFiles("*.doc"))
    allFile.AddRange(objDI.GetFiles("*.docx"))

    Me.showfiles.DataSource = allFile
    Me.showfiles.DataBind()
End Sub
```

main code

```
<ul class="thumbnails">
   <asp:DataList ID="showfiles" runat="server" RepeatColumns="6" CellPadding="10" RepeatLayout="flow">
         <ItemTemplate>
               <li class="span2"><a class="thumbnail" href="#"><asp:ImageButton ID="folderfiles" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# string.Format("upload/files/{0}", DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Name")) %>' ToolTip='<%# Bind("Name") %>' height="82" width="119" /></a></li>
         </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:DataList>
```

works fine with images, but if i add a document like a pdf file i get this.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9bT4.png

then it add the textbox, how can i add an if statsment or something that can add:

pdficon.jpg for .pdf files

docicon.jpg for .doc files

zipicon.jpg for .zip files

so if the file is an image then it works like now, and when the file is an pdf or doc file, then it use the icon image and display that !?

.....EDIT.....EDIT......EDIT........EDIT.........EDIT.........EDIT

Thx its works
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKL55.png

but when i click one of the files i get and error page, with no error number, but a text with.

.......... <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %>  ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation .....

I cant download/See the image/pdf file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement a method returning your image url like this:

```
Private Function getImageUrl(filename As String) As String

    Select Case Path.GetExtension(filename)
        Case "pdf"
            Return "pdficon.jpg"
        Case "doc"
            Return "docicon.jpg"
        Case "zip"
            Return "zipicon.jpg"
    End Select

    Return String.Format("upload/files/{0}", filename)
End Function
```

and use it in your markup:

...    `ImageUrl='<%# getImageUrl(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Name")) %>'` ...

Comment: ok and will this still show the real images if the file is copenhagen.jpg !?

Comment: how will this look like in asp.net vb, cant get telerik C# to vb.net to translate it.

Comment: Hi Michal Klouda thx for reply, im almost there, plz. see Edit in main question..

Comment: Update your anchor href, put the right url instead of #, the same way you do with the button's ImageUrl.. Now I realized what you might be doing, are you really displaying just thumbnails in your index page or the full images?

Answer (score 0):

Would it be cleaner to pick up those different file types in a different collection, and handle them separately (ie in a separate display loop with their specific thumbnail)?

Or use a dictionary rather than a list, so you can store the file type and query on that when deciding which image to display.

Comment: and how do i do this, im new to this !!